# Adobe Reader tabs illegible: grey on grey

Tags: 12.04, adobe-reader

I'm using Adobe Reader 9.5.5 (the default version to my knowledge) on 12.04.3, and the inactive tabs are a nearly-illegible grey on an ever-so-slightly darker grey gradient:

[image: Adobe Reader with grey-on-grey tabs]

How can I improve the contrast?

Comment: Have you changed any of the themes?

Comment: No; stock themes AFIAK.

Answer (score 1):

Open file /usr/share/themes/ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc using gedit, and change fg_color from #4c4c4c to #000000. (source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2031342)

Comment: Thanks, 4.5 years later this solution still works, except need 'Ambiance' instead of 'ambiance'.  The new value gets overwritten on every restart though, know a way around that?